# How to solve stability problems in Google Dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, dataflow

I have a Dataflow job that has been running stable for several months.
The last 3 days or so, I've problems with the job, it's getting stuck after a certain amount of time and the only thing I can do is stop the job and start a new one. This happened after 2, 6 and 24 hours of processing. Here is the latest exception:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.options.StreamingDataflowWorkerOptions$WindmillServerStubFactory.create (StreamingDataflowWorkerOptions.java:183)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.options.StreamingDataflowWorkerOptions$WindmillServerStubFactory.create (StreamingDataflowWorkerOptions.java:169)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.ProxyInvocationHandler.returnDefaultHelper (ProxyInvocationHandler.java:592)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.ProxyInvocationHandler.getDefault (ProxyInvocationHandler.java:533)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke (ProxyInvocationHandler.java:158)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy54.getWindmillServerStub (Unknown Source)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker.<init> (StreamingDataflowWorker.java:677)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker.fromDataflowWorkerHarnessOptions (StreamingDataflowWorker.java:562)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker.main (StreamingDataflowWorker.java:274)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Loading windmill_service failed:
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.windmill.WindmillServer.<clinit> (WindmillServer.java:42)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: No space left on device
at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0 (Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write (FileDispatcherImpl.java:60)
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer (IOUtil.java:93)
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write (IOUtil.java:65)
at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.write (FileChannelImpl.java:211)
at java.nio.channels.Channels.writeFullyImpl (Channels.java:78)
at java.nio.channels.Channels.writeFully (Channels.java:101)
at java.nio.channels.Channels.access$000 (Channels.java:61)
at java.nio.channels.Channels$1.write (Channels.java:174)
at java.nio.file.Files.copy (Files.java:2909)
at java.nio.file.Files.copy (Files.java:3027)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.windmill.WindmillServer.<clinit> (WindmillServer.java:39)
```

Seems like there is no space left on a device, but shouldn't this be managed by Google? Or is this an error in my job somehow?

UPDATE:
The workflow is as follows:

- Reading mass data from PubSub (up to 1500/s)
- Filter some messages
- Keeping session window on key and grouping by it
- Sort the data and do calculations
- Output the data to another PubSub

Comment: Dataflow runs on workers, which are standard GCE machines with an special image, but if in your workflow you are downloading files and you don't delete them, you may run into storage issues. Can you share your work flow so we can understand more what you are doing?

Comment: I've added the workflow.

Comment: Are you allowing late data? If so, for how long? Are you using streaming engine?

Comment: The error, `No space left on device`, does look like an issue with downloading files and never deleting them.

Comment: So what consists of a file download when using Beam/Dataflow?

Comment: @Iñigo Standard settings for late date. I use session windows with gaps of 5 minutes. No streaming engine; I tried it, but it worked even worse.

Comment: Worse? normal: `If a streaming job uses Streaming Engine, then the default is 30 GB; otherwise, the default is 400 GB.` 10 time less space on devices, you fail quicker

Comment: I am trying now to run the job on a single thread (--numberOfWorkerHarnessThreads=1). This seems promising. The job can easily keep up with the pubsub messages and the CPU use and output are very smooth. With the standard settings it was very spiky, sometimes not delivering output for a while and then suddenly outputting 1M messages at a time.

Answer (score 3):

You can increase the storage capacity in the parameter of your pipelise. Look at this one `diskSizeGb` in this [page](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/specifying-exec-params)

In addition, more you keep data in memory, more you need memory. It's the case for the windows, if you never close them, or if  you allow late data for too long time, you need a lot of memory to keep all these data up.

Tune either your pipeline, or your machine type. Or both!

Comment: How do I close windows actively? I use session windows with 5 minute gap duration.

Comment: The window session is closed when the gap duration is reached + allow late data duration.

Comment: I haven't set any allowedLateness. The default is 0, i.e. no allowed lateness?

Comment: Yes. Do you have a lot of concurrent window open in the same time? Do you have a lot of data in each window?

Comment: About 25.000 open windows with around 100 messages each. Each message is around 200 bytes.

Comment: I think that a review of the pipeline is needed. Even if you use bigger disk, the problem will occur, like a memory leak. You can share it here if there is nothing confidential, or try to reproduce minimal pipeline with only basic transform (but, if there is a memory leak, the minimal pipeline could not fail as the real one..)